# Generalisation of spanning tree in simplex

Tags: convex-polytopes, simplicial-stuff

This is a question I asked on Stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4004734/400240) but I did not receive an answer (I think it was too hard). Per someone's suggestion I put it here.

Let $\Delta$ be some $n$-simplex. Note that if some $(n-1)$-dimensional affine hyperplane $U$ intersects $\Delta$, then $U$ separates the vertices of $\Delta$. Therefore, if $T$ is some spanning tree of the vertices then $U$ must intersect $T$. It follows that a sufficient condition for $U$ not intersecting $\Delta$ is $U$ not intersecting $T$. (With spanning tree I mean a union of edges that contains no cycles such that every vertex belongs to one of the edges).

I am interested in the following generalization of a spanning tree: how do we characterize a minimal family $T$ of $k$-faces of $\Delta$ such that any $(n-k)$-dimensional affine space $U$ intersects $\Delta$ if and only if $U$ intersects $T$? With 'minimal' I mean that taking away any member of $T$ also removes this property.

As an example, such a minimal family of 2-faces for a tetrahedron (such that any line intersecting the tetrahedron intersects the family) is any selection of three of the four faces.

I am looking for alternative characterizations for the family than the one I gave above. Also other combinatoric/graph-theoretic properties are of interest. Perhaps methods to construct such families even?

Comment: The order of quantifiers is confused.  Given your example (of a spanning tree) you probably are asking the following: "Show that there exist a fixed $T$ so that for any $U$ we have $U \cap T$ empty if and only if $U \cap \Delta$ is empty."  Is that the case?

Comment: In your definition of "spanning tree", shouldn't "no triangles" be "no cycles"?

Comment: Andreas, you are right, I corrected my mistake. Sam, I changed the order of quantifiers and hope it is now clear what I'm looking for (it is what you're saying with the addition that T is minimal) (and, of course, it exists, but I would like a few more details if possible).